# Logistic regression error (Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x') in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am doing logistic regression but I am getting error. I checked the dependent variable and it is `0` and `1` continuous variable (not factor).
[Attached](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZx97WXZPDJOvXmKFcbX0kXPmzuRLJF0X9L7) you can see my dataframe and here is my code

```
Publish::publish(glm(MAE_and_SCI ~ Ansize
                           +Ejecfrac
                           +  Urgent.emergent_procedure, data=d,family="binomial"))
```

I got this error many times even after doing several answers on similar question

> Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  :   NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

My data structure is as follow:

```
data.frame':    469 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ MAE_and_SCI              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Ansize                   : num  6 8.4 6.2 5.2 6.2 6.3 6 7.6 5.6 6.7 ...
 $ Ejecfrac                 : int  60 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
 $ Nyhaclas..34             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Urgent.emergent_procedure: Factor w/ 2 levels "elective","Urgent/emergent procedure": 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ PRBC_given1              : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PRBC                     : int  2 3 3 1 0 0 3 1 5 8 ...
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, the model fits with no errors. But only after coercing the columns read in as character to numeric (except for `Urgent.emergent_procedure`).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for your help. I added my data structure. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Now it works after I closed all opened R programs and restarted single RStudio. Appreciate your input. Upvoted